# Issue in jndi lookup in spring and JBoss7

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, datasource, jndi

I am using Spring, JPA and JBoss 7 in my project.

I am getting the below error while jndi lookup of data source as below

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rulesUI]] (MSC service thread 1-4) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rulesDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up RuleDS, service service jboss.naming.context.java.RuleDS is not started
```

Here is my standalone.xml in JBoss where datasource is configured.

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/RuleDS" pool-name="rule_poc_schema" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@medicare-ins.cxgvce1cqpuy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306:MEDICARE</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>APPLICATION_MEA_DEV</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

In my Spring configuration file, I am accessing it using:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:/RuleDS" id="rulesDataSource"/>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Could try this way:

At Spring Context we have:

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss-datasource" /> 
  </bean>
```

At Jboss I have like this:

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>jboss-datasource</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/shoppingDB</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password>123456</password>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>
            org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
        </exception-sorter-class-name>
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>MySql</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

make sure you have already spring-context jar

Hope this helps,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First I would check log for following line:

```
[org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/RuleDS]
```

I also use the full name:

```
java:jboss/datasources/MyDSName
```

Maybe this is the case?

Comment: the above name should be used in standalone.xml file or in spring configuration file?

Comment: Both, but I don't think this this is the case, you may try. I've seeen examples as yours in jboss guide. First see if Jboss registered it correctly. Go to admin console http://localhost:9990/console -> Select Runtime and Datasources from left menu. You should see the Name, JNDI and Enabled status